# Get all users in a the top-level group (all users are members of that group, but exclude users who are also members of other, children groups as well)

Tags: mysql, relation

Theoretically I have two tables: users, groups with a third table user_group that joins them (tells which users are in which group).

Here's how the groups are structured (tree-like):

> 1 root
>
> 1.1 child1
>
> 1.2 child2

ALL users are assigned to at least the `root` group. Additionally, they may be (but not necessary) assigned to a different group that is a children of the root group (e.g. child1 or child2).

Given a group ID, I'd like to retrieve users of ONLY that group ID. The funny part is the following scenario: if the root group's ID is provided, we should only retrieve users who are present in the root group ONLY - they should not be a member of any other child group.

Answer (score 0):

There another, but quite annoying way:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT idUser, idGroup
  FROM UserGroup
  GROUP BY idUser
  HAVING COUNT(idGroup) < 2
)
WHERE idGroup = <group's id you're looking for>
```

I said annoying because I don't like double Selects.

Old answer below:

With a structure like this:

```
Users      UserGroup      Groups
------     -----------    ------
idUser     idUserGroup    idGroup
           idUser
           idGroup
```

You could try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idUser
FROM UserGroup AS UG
WHERE UG.idGroup=1
GROUP BY UG.idGroup
```

Where *1*, in the *where* clause is the *idGroup* you want to search for:

```
 WHERE UG.idGroup=<idGroup>
```

Comment: Correct, but it will also retrieve users who are simulataneously in the root group and in groups children to root. I'd like to retrieve only those who are in root, but are not in other groups.